# How to fix performance issue with rest api calls in swift 4, usrlsession

Tags: ios, swift4

When I hit the api from simulator/device, it's taking almost 18-20 seconds to fetch data from api response, where as the same API is getting response in 1.4 seconds in POSTMAN Application. This issue is happening for almost all APIs. Even I have tried with Alamofire, but same issue is happening. How to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

I'm using below code in network manager class:

```
typealias serverResponseBlock = (_ success: Bool, _ message: String, _ dataDict: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void


class func createRequest(httpMethod : HTTPMethod, endPoint : String, parameters : [String : Any], completion: @escaping serverResponseBlock) -> Void {

    let baseUrl = ApiConstants.kBaseUrl + ApiConstants.kPath + endPoint
    var request = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: baseUrl)!)
    request.timeoutInterval = 60
    request.httpMethod = httpMethod.rawValue
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
    request.addValue("Bearer \(StoredValues.Token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
                    APIManager.processResponse(responseObject: json, block: completion)
                } catch {
                    print("error")
                }
            }else{
                completion(false, "Could not complete your request", [:])
            }   
        }else{
            completion(false, /error?.localizedDescription, [:])
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Does it really takes 20 seconds to reach `if error == nil`? Or when the API has end the response process?

Comment: Is it taking 20 seconds to retrieve the data or to show it on the UI?  Are you dispatching UI updates on the main queue?  What do you do in the `completion` closure?

Comment: just for getting response itself its taking 20 seconds either success or failure. once response is available UI update is very quick, no lag in UI Update

Comment: i think your backend is lazy otherwise i am using same kind code in swift its taking about  4 seconds to get response even for heavy records about 20 thousand.